# How should I express 太 ~ 了 in a verb?

Tags: grammar

太 + adjective + 了 means "too ~". For example:

> 这个女人太漂亮了。
>
> 这个星期我太忙了。

However, how can I express the "too ~" phrase in a verb? For example:

> I love her too much.

One possible solution is to use 很:

> 我很爱她。

Another possible solution is to use the degree complement - 得.

> 我爱她爱得太好。

But neither might not be the best choice here (I don't know). So is there any other or possibly more natural way for natives to express 太～了 pattern in a verb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

太 + verb + 了 can be a correct usage for some verbs. Like, 我太爱她了！ 我太喜欢了！

However, not all verbs can work in the structure of 太 + verb + 了.  So far, I don't have a good rule to sort out all the verbs that can work in this structure.

It seems that those verbs about one's feeling like 高兴，激动，兴奋，喜欢，爱，感动，can work.

能/会+verb can also be placed in  太 + 能+verb + 了, such as 太能/会玩了， 太能/会吃了，太能/会打了， ...

Subject + verb + 太 + adv + 了 is also possible. Like, 你球打得太棒了！ 太棒了！

Comment: Ah I got confused here. I wish any grammar text wrote both patterns in the same page...

Comment: Note that the former usage is not appropriate for some verbs. e.g. "eat too much" is not 太吃了 but 吃太多了 @Blaszard

Comment: I think the first pattern works only when the verb is about one's feeling

Comment: I think basically, you can put any descriptive word in the middle of 太...了。 like 太强了， 太笨了， 太厉害了， 太烦了， 太美了， 太爱了，etc.

Comment: We can say 太能吃了 in that case. Maybe, I made the answer a bit simple.

Comment: I found that [according to Chinese Grammar Wiki](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22excessively%22_with_%22tai%22), this usage of 太～了 on a verb is only available to some specific verbs. Is this true? In that case, what should I use to express the stress?

Comment: @dan (A response to the comment that starts with `I think basically, you can...`) They are all adverbs so it is OK to use 太~了 pattern; my question is regarding the phrase along with a verb.

Comment: @Blaszard, "*Note for the more advanced learner: This pattern can be used with modal verbs (e.g. 会 (huì), 能 (néng)) as well as psychological verbs (e.g. 喜欢 (xǐhuan), 想 (xiǎng), 爱 (ài)) to intensify the degree. *". This is pretty much what we are addressing here. There are more verbs that can be used in this structure, but we can not think all out.